# RelativeView stuck at top of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to place an ImageView inside my RelativeLayout that is positioned about 3/4 down the screen, but as soon as I add an ImageView to the RelativeLayout, the layout and the image get snapped to the top of the screen and I am not sure how to move it from there.

This is what it looks like whenever I add an ImageView to the RelativeLayout

[image]

But I want it positioned just above the "Ready" button

This is the `.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="74dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/readyButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/player1FlipAvatar"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity_flip_coin_lobby"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="55dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/defaultavatarmale" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you don't understand RelativeLayout well enough.

All Views placed inside RelativeLayout will automatically be placed ontop of each other in the top left corner of the RelativeLayout.

If you want to move it, you need to 'align' it.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="74dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/readyButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/player1FlipAvatar"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity_flip_coin_lobby"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="55dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/defaultavatarmale" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

By aligning the ImageView to the bottom of the RelativeLayout, it should be placed above the Ready button IF your RelativeLayout ends right above the Ready button.

If you want to center the ImageView, you can add in `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`.

You can read more about RelativeLayout here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative

However, there's 2 curious things about your xml code.

1. Why are you placing an ImageView of height 80dp inside a RelativeLayout of height 74dp? It's basically purposely looking for trouble.
2. Why are you using a RelativeLayout if you're using ConstraintLayout already? One of the main benefits of using a ConstraintLayout is so you don't have to use nested layouts. With the power and control of ConstraintLayout, you can actually rearrange almost all views to any design you want without nesting another layout like RelativeLayout inside of it.

I'm just guessing that you're using ConstraintLayout because you used `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` in your RelativeLayout and these types of 'constraints' only exist for ConstraintLayout.

So if you're already using a ConstraintLayout and your Ready Button is inside the ConstraintLayout, you simply need to do:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/player1FlipAvatar"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/readyButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity_flip_coin_lobby"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="55dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/defaultavatarmale" />
```

You don't need a RelativeLayout to place the ImageView above the Ready Button.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. It showed me how little I know about `.xml` and how much more research I need to do. I may be doing this incorrectly, but I have added the RelativeLayout because I am going to be adding multiple elements such as text and a button inside that I want to all be grouped together so they are easier to constrain. Another reason is that I want the RelativeView to have a different background color to add some contrast. I am guessing there is a better way to do this though. The 74dp vs 80dp was simply an accident because I added the ImageView first. Thanks for help

Comment: Definitely read up more about the different types of layouts used in Android because each layout has it's own behavior and rules. For example, `LinearLayout` automatically lays out added Views in the vertical or horizontal order they were added in. `RelativeLayout` allows you to freely arrange Views through aligning them to other Views. On the other hand, `ConstraintLayout` is definitely the most powerful and gives you even more freedom and control in arranging your views. So if you're using `ConstraintLayout`, you don't really need the `RelativeLayout` to group together Views.

Comment: Keep in mind that layout specific code don't work outside of their layouts. So constraints will only work in ConstraintLayout and alignments will only work in RelativeLayout. These lines will be ignored if you use them in another layout. As for adding a separate background color, there's definitely multiple ways to do this. One way is what you're doing which is creating a separate container for the Views and changing the background color there. Another common way I've seen is just to add a View under the other Views and changing that View's background color.

Comment: awesome thanks for all the help. Do you know what the best tool would be to use if I wanted to change the background just behind the ImageView I added and have the color stretch the width of the screen? Would adding a rectangle and placing it on the area I want to be a different color be the best method?

Comment: It's really hard to say what would be the best option, since there's pros/cons for each solution. But for something simple like this where the pros/cons doesn't really outweigh each other, don't focus too hard on what's the best option. Give the colored rectangle solution you said a try and if you like it and it produces the results you want, use it.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the `relative layout` and `button` with `linear layout` orientation vertical and adjust gravity as you like

```
 <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:gravity="bottom"
       android:orientation="vertical">
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="74dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/readyButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/player1FlipAvatar"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_activity_flip_coin_lobby"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="55dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp"
        tools:src="@drawable/defaultavatarmale" />
    </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```